# Data Structure to store a model information using Objective C and GLKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, data-structures, opengl-es

I am developing my small engine for 3D in iOS. I need a suggestion of what data structure is better for performance. I want to stay using C and objective-C. It's better no C++.
My idea is to use GLKVector3 and GLKVector4 for storing vertex information. 
Now this is for storing just one vertex. However a geometry contains multiple vertex.

What I want to do is to create a Geometry class in Objective-C which can store multiple GLKVector3 for each vertex position and multiple GLKVector4 for each vertex color. This class will also provide functions of the type:

- (GLvoid *)getRawDataForVertices;
- (GLvoid *)getRawDataForIndices;

to get the stored data.

But this is not very relevant to the question.

What I'd like to know is which data structure (for my instance variables) should be preferable to store multiple GLKVector3 or GLKVector4 inside a NSObject class .

My class in fact should have 2 properties of the type

@property (nonatomic) TYPEOFDATASTRUCTURE colors; //an array that contains GLKVector4
@property (nonatomic) TYPEOFDATASTRUCTURE positions; //an array that contains GLKVector3

Is it better/possible to use a NSArray ??
If yes should I prefer it beside a simple GLKVector3* pointer?

Thank you for your time.

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to work in OpenGL you need to get used to using dynamically allocated memory buffers and C arrays. Period. That's what you have to pass in to OpenGL, and you will get both more compact storage and more efficient processing by doing it that way. Do NOT use NSArrays. You will just end up converting your data back and forth between formats every time you want to do something with it.

You want pointers like this:

```
GLKVector4 *colors;
GLKVector3 *positions;
```

And then code like this:

```
int pixels = height*width;
colors = malloc(pixels*sizeof(GLKVector4));
positions = malloc(pixels*sizeof(GLKVector3));
```

If you want to make your pointers into properties you can do that too, but be aware that every time you use self.colors[x], you are adding an extra method call, and if you are looping through >1 million pixels, like on a retina iPad, it starts to have a performance impact.

P.S. When you use malloc, be aware that you are then responsible to free the memory when you are done with it. ARC does not manage this type of memory for you, and the blocks tend to be large. You will quickly run out of memory and crash if you create large buffers and don't free them before creating a new buffer.

Comment: I was hoping there was an easier and safer way than malloc. But if this is the better solution I will use it.